# finding particular word in each line and display result in unix shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to check the presence of any word like `raj` or `rohit` (ignoring case) as an independent word in each and every line of the file. If the match found then pass "Found"
and if not then "Not Found" in another file. So there must be entries for  each line.

Example

Input file say (`input.txt`)

```
raj ramu ram 
ram rohit sanjay sonu
savita ram raj rohit
raju ramu babita saurabhROHIT
raj sunita savita 
sachin sonu
```

output file (say `file.out`)

```
Found
Found
Found
Not Found
Found
Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```perl
#!awk -f
{
  print /\<(raj|rohit)\>/ ? "Found" : "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: problem solved ... really appreciable quick and correct response.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk -v s1='(^| )raj( |$)' -v s2='(^| )rohit( |$)' '{
          print ($0~s1 || $0~s2)? "found": "not found"}' file
found
found
found
not found
found
not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU awk`, which supports `\y` (and `\<` + `\>`) to match word boundaries [[1]](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html):

```
$ awk '!/\yraj\y/&&!/\yrohit\y/{printf "Not "} {print "Found"}' test.txt
Found
Found
Found
Not Found
Found
Not Found

$ awk '!/\<raj\>/&&!/\<rohit\>/{printf "Not "} {print "Found"}' test.txt
Found
Found
Found
Not Found
Found
Not Found
```

`busybox awk` also seems to support `\<` and `\>` (but not `\y`):

```
$ busybox awk '!/\<raj\>/&&!/\<rohit\>/{printf "Not "} {print "Found"}' test.txt
Found
Found
Found
Not Found
Found
Not Found
```

Comment: +1 for the `GNU awk` info; which `nawk` are you referring to? On some platforms, e.g., Ubuntu 12.04, `nawk` is merely a symlink to `gawk`. As for why it is `\y`, not `\b`: "In other GNU software, the word-boundary operator is ‘\b’. However, that conflicts with the awk language's definition of ‘\b’ as backspace, so gawk uses a different letter. An alternative method would have been to require two backslashes in the GNU operators, but this was deemed too confusing." - http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html

Comment: @mklement0 Heh, you're right...I removed the `nawk` reference but added the `busybox` `awk` implementation which also supports `\<`/`\>` (but not `\y` it seems).

Comment: Thanks for the update; I took the liberty of removing the `<` before your input filenames.